# Running gitlab and jenkins with https in docker swarm

Tags: docker, jenkins, https, gitlab, docker-swarm

**Context:** I want to run gitlab and jenkins in docker swarm with https. I succeeded in making them run on the default port(8080 for jenkins and 80 for gitlab with http).

**My problem:** is when I try to run for example gitlab on the port 443, I get nothing even though I published my container on that port and modified the external url on the "gitlab.rb" file(I've been following the official doc).
And for Jenkins it's even harder to make it run on https, it's either adding a reverse proxy or SSL certificate.

```
> sudo docker service create -u 0 --name  jenkins_stack \
> --network devops-net --replicas 1 --publish 8443:8443 \
> --publish 50000:50000 --mount src=jenkins-volume,dst=/var/jenkins_home \
> --hostname jenkins   jenkins/jenkins
> 
> 
> sudo docker service create -u 0 --name  gitlabstack \
> --network devops-net --replicas 1 --publish 80:80 --publish 443:443  \
> --mount src=gitlab-data,dst=/var/opt/gitlab \
> --mount src=gitlab-logs,dst=/var/log/gitlab \
> --mount src=gitlab-config,dst=/etc/gitlab \
> --hostname gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce
```

Above you will find the docker lines to create the services.

I'd really appreciate it, if someone can share any video or tutorial on how to run gitlab/jenkins on docker swarm with https.

I'm sorry if I've been unclear.

Comment: do it once with traefik.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisBecke for your answer ! I'll try to do it and I'll reach you back.